# ejabberd mod_register allow registration only from a specified IP

Tags: configuration, ejabberd

I'm trying to get `ejabberd` to allow for in-channel registration only from a specific IP, using `mod_register`'s `ip_access` clause.

To do this, I added this line to the `mod_register` block in my `ejabberd.cfg`:

```
{ip_access, [{allow, "the.allowed.ip.address"}]}
```

... And restarted `ejabberd` via `ejabberdctl restart`. The server came back online with no warnings or errors logged in `/var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log`.

Unfortunately, with this line of code, I could still perform in-channel registration from a non-whitelisted IP using Adium as a client. I decided to amend the line above by adding:

```
{ip_access, [{allow, "the.allowed.ip.address"}, {deny, all}]}
```

... Running the risk of causing all registrations to throw a 403 "Unauthorized" status. Strangely, now, when I try to register from *any* IP, including the whitelisted one, I get a 503 "Service unavailable" status message.

How can I get `ejabberd` to allow in-channel registration from a specific IP, and that IP alone?

Comment: Which version of ejabberd are you using ?

Comment: @MickaëlRémond I'm using 2.1.11 which is what's available via Ubuntu's default repos. I've also tried 15.09 which uses YAML for its configuration file, but encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the restriction is supposed to be used. You can find an example (in .yaml) in [ejabberd documentation for mod_register](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modregister):

That's not how it works in ejabberd 15.x. You need three things to be able to limit registration from IP:
- ACL definition for IP.
- Access rule defining for which ACL you want to allow or deny access.
- `mod_register` configuration linking ip_access to your access rule.

For the (very old) 2.1.11, it is very different, but definitely does not use the all keyword for deny.

ejabberd 2.1.11 documentation show example as:

```
{acl, shortname, {user_glob, "??"}}.
%% The same using regexp:
%%{acl, shortname, {user_regexp, "^..?$"}}.

{access, register, [{deny, shortname},
                    {allow, all}]}.

{modules,
 [
  ...
  {mod_register, [{access, register},
                  {ip_access, [{allow, "127.0.0.0/8"},
                               {deny, "0.0.0.0/0"}]}
  ]},
  ...
 ]}.
```

As you see deny should match IP address blocks to deny.